# open Excel workbook to specific Sheet View of specific worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a shared Excel document in Sharepoint, I can create named "Sheet Views" in the View tab.  Each sheet view has a saved filter.  I would like to be able to create a link that opens the document to a specific sheet view on a specific worksheet.

I can successfully specify the worksheet by appending: ?activeCell=WorksheetABC!A1

I don't think there is a way to specify a sheet view but maybe there is?

Some links of URL arguments where I didn't find a solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-iframe-url-parameters-to-make-content/deac20a7-d5a1-4933-8dc0-31159c00d10d?auth=1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773

Comment: I would also like to have a solution for that.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and couldn't find it either, so I created a feature request on Microsoft's feedback portal at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e9496bfc-e2ae-ed11-a81b-002248519701.